# Plotting function + labelling only the units on my x-axis

Tags: axis, tkz-fct

this feels like a stupid question but I can't find a solution.

I'm trying to try to make this work and I don't why it doesn't...

Here's my code :

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \tkzInit[xmin=0, ymin=0, xstep=0.25, ystep = 1, xmax = 2.25, ymax = 10]
    \tkzGrid(0,0)(2.25,10)
    \tkzDrawX[right, label = \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
                Temps de \\ parcours \\ (en h)
            \end{minipage}]
    \tkzDrawY[above right, label = \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        Distance \\ parcourue\\ (en km)
    \end{minipage}]
    \tkzLabelY
    \tkzLabelX[xstep = 1]
    
    \tkzFct[very thick, color=blue, domain = 0:0.25]{12*x}
    \tkzFct[very thick, color=blue, domain = 0.25:0.75]{3}
    \tkzFct[very thick, color=blue, domain = 0.75:1.85]{84/13 * x - 24/13}
    
    \tkzFct[very thick, dotted, color=red, domain = 0:2]{5*x}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The function don't plot like I imagine they should be... I've added a picture of what I get.
[image]

Furthermore, I'd like to have only 0, 1 and 2 on my x-axis and not any other numbers. How should I do that ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found it !

for my x-axis I did this :
\tkzInit[xmin=0, ymin=0, xstep=1, ystep = 1, xmax = 2, ymax = 10]
\tkzGrid(0,0)(2.25,10)
\tkzGridsub,subxstep=0.25,subystep=1(2.25,10)

the first grid is on the units and the subgrid is on a 0.25 step for the x-axis. There's probably a better way to do this but it works !

As for my function, I think my 0.25 xstep was a problem that caused them to plot incorrectly, because as soon as I changed it to xstep = 1, it worked.

So here's my working solution :

```
    \documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}

\begin{document}  
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale = 4]
    \tkzInit[xmin=0, ymin=0, xstep=1, ystep = 1, xmax = 2, ymax = 10]
    \tkzGrid(0,0)(2.25,10)
    \tkzGrid[sub,subxstep=0.25,subystep=1](0,0)(2.25,10)
    \tkzDrawX[right, label = \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
                Temps de \\ parcours \\ (en h)
            \end{minipage}]
    \tkzDrawY[above right, label = \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        Distance \\ parcourue\\ (en km)
    \end{minipage}]
    \tkzLabelY
    \tkzLabelX[xstep = 1]
    
    \tkzFct[very thick, color=blue, domain = 0:0.25]{12*x}
    \tkzFct[very thick, color=blue, domain = 0.25:0.75]{3}
    \tkzFct[very thick, color=blue, domain = 0.75:1.85]{6.46156 * x - 1.84617}
    
    \tkzFct[very thick, dotted, color=red, domain = 0:2]{5*x}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and the end result :
[image]